# Need help on C# Twitch bot

Tags: c#, chat, bots, twitch

Hey I want to create a chat bot for Twitch and I'm kind of a beginner in those things and this is my work so far:

Form1.cs as below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MyTwitchChat
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private string username;
        private string password;

        bool joined;

        IRCClient ircClient;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            username = userNameTB.Text;
            password = TokenBox.Text;
            ircClient = new IRCClient("irc.chat.twitch.tv", 6667, username, password);
            ircClient.joinChannel("deadlycursed");

            timer1.Start();

        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            if (ircClient.tcpClient.Available > 0 )
            {

                string message = ircClient.inputStream.ReadLine();

                ChatBox.Items.Add(message);
                if (message.Contains("!Hallo"))  
                        ircClient.sendChatMessage("Hi!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

IRCClient.cs as below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.IO;

namespace MyTwitchChat
{
    class IRCClient
    {
        private string username;
        private string channel;
        private string nickname = "deadlycursed";
        public TcpClient tcpClient;
        public StreamReader inputStream;
        public StreamWriter outputStream;


        public IRCClient(string ip, int port, string username, string password)
        {
            this.username = username;
            tcpClient = new TcpClient(ip, port);
            inputStream = new StreamReader(tcpClient.GetStream());
            outputStream = new StreamWriter(tcpClient.GetStream());

            outputStream.WriteLine("PASS " + password);
            outputStream.WriteLine("NICK " + nickname);
            outputStream.WriteLine("USER " + username + " 0 * :" + nickname );
            outputStream.Flush();
        }

        public void joinChannel(string channel)
        {
            this.channel = channel;
            outputStream.WriteLine("JOIN #" + channel);
            outputStream.Flush();

        }

        public void sendIRCMessage(string message)
        {
            outputStream.WriteLine(message);
            outputStream.Flush();
        }

        public void sendChatMessage(string message)
        {
            outputStream.WriteLine(":" + nickname + "!" + username + "@" + nickname + ".tmi.twitch.tv PRIVMSG #"
                + channel + ":" + message);
            outputStream.Flush();
        }

        public string getMessage()
        {
            string message = inputStream.ReadLine();
            return message;
        }
    }
}
```

And I would like to know why I actually can't send messages or receive them?
Sometimes the reading thing works and sometimes not and I can't write to the chat with my bot

Answer (score 1):

There are libraries for helping you do this, so you could either see how they work or use them directly.

For example most popular on NuGet seems to be:

TwitchLib - Twitch Chat and API C# Library - https://github.com/swiftyspiffy/TwitchLib